# How to override functions.php in child theme?

Tags: functions, theme-development, child-theme

I have a theme and I need to override some specific parts|behavior of it specifically on the `functions.php` file. I know the best practice here is doing this at child theme by placing a custom `functions.php`. Now this is part of the original file:

```
function mytheme_setup() {
    ...
    add_image_size( 'mytheme-l-thumbs' , 750 , 423 , true);
    add_image_size( 'mytheme-m-thumbs' , 555 , 313 , true);
    add_image_size( 'mytheme-s-thumbs' , 450 , 254 , true);
    add_image_size( 'mytheme-square-thumbs' , 750 , 750 , true);
    add_image_size( 'mytheme-nocrop-thumbs' , 750 , 1500 , false);

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );
```

And I want to override each `add_image_size` by set `crop` to false on my child theme. I have tried by copying & pasting the function on child theme but I ended up with this error:

> Cannot redeclare mytheme_setup() (previously declared in /themes/mytheme-child/functions.php:11) in /themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 88

How I can do that?

Comment: @jgraup that was my first though but I am not sure at all, will try now, thanks

Comment: @jgraup nope, didn't work, see my edit at OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is hooked, it is easy to change that in a child theme. What you need to do is

- Remove the original call back function
- Copy the function to your child theme and rename it.
- Do your customizations as needed
- Rehook your call back function

You can try the following:

```
// Remove the callback function from the hook
remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );

// Copy the function, rename and do what you need
function my_new_callback()
{
    // Modify what you need
}

// Rehook your custom callback
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_new_callback' );
```

Comment: Glad it worked, enjoy ;-)